# How to store all insert statements from the script file into Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have sql script file with all insert statments like below

```
 INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME) VALUES
    (1, 'Madhava'),
    (2, 'Rao'),
    (3, 'Tmr');  

    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ADDRESS(ID, CITY) VALUES
    (1, 'Bangalore'),
    (2, 'Chirala'),
    (3, 'Pune');
```

How do i store the each statment individually into ArrayList like below

```
 INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'Madhava');
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME) VALUES  (2, 'Rao');
 INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ADDRESS(ID, CITY) VALUES(1, 'Bangalore');
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ADDRESS(ID, CITY) VALUES(2, 'Chirala');
```

how do i parse the sql file and store each statment individually into Arraylist like above?

Comment: You could do a string split on the semi-colon character and build up the array list that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume we have

```
String data = 
          " INSERT INTO PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID, NAME) VALUES\r\n"
        + "    (1, 'Madhava'),\r\n" + "    (2, 'Rao'),\r\n"
        + "    (3, 'Tmr');  \r\n" + "\r\n"
        + "    INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ADDRESS(ID, CITY) VALUES\r\n"
        + "    (1, 'Bangalore'),\r\n" + "    (2, 'Chirala'),\r\n"
        + "    (3, 'Pune'); ";
List<String> inserts = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(data); //you can also use new Scanner(new File("location/of/your/textfile.sql"));
```

Your solution may look like (we are using empty lines to separate data into sections):

```
String command = "";
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine().trim();
    if (line.isEmpty() || command.isEmpty()) {
        command = line;
    } else {
        String values = line.replaceAll(",$", ";");//replace `,` at the end with ;
        inserts.add(command + " " + values);
    }
}
```

Or maybe simpler (we simply set command to line which starts with "INSERT" and create concatenation of command and non-empty line):

```
String command = "";
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine().trim();
    //ignore empty lines
    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
        if (line.startsWith("INSERT ")) {
            command = line;
        } else {
            //lets change `),` to `);`
            String values = line.replaceAll(",$", ";");
            inserts.add(command + " " + values);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... very useful